# Creating ExpandableListView with data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm creating a task manager app. And I have a problem with showing these tasks in `ExpandableListView`, I'm using it because every task may have subtasks. This is my Database structure:

[image: Database Structure].

ExpandableListView Adapter may work well. But I have a problem with reading data from firebase in `fillData()` method.

**`Activity` with `ExpandableListView`:**

```
public class Tasks extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    CustomExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;

    List<String> tasks;
    Map<String, List<String>> subtasks;

    private FirebaseDatabase firebasedatabase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tasks);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);

        firebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebasedatabase.getReference("Tasks");
        fillData();
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, tasks, subtasks);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);




        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.notes:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notes.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.tasks:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.goals:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Goals.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.statistics:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Statistics.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.add:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void fillData()
    {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(tasks.size() > 0) tasks.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                  String taskName = (String) ds.child("Tasks").getValue();
                  tasks.add(taskName);
                }

                expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ExpandableListView Adapter:**

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> listHeader;
private Map<String, List<String>> listChildren;
public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listHeader, Map<String, List<String>> listChildren){
    this.context = context;
    this.listHeader = listHeader;
    this.listChildren = listChildren;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.listHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listChildren.get(listHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.listChildren.get(this.listHeader.get(groupPosition));
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String header = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_header, null);
    }

    TextView headerOfGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_text);
    headerOfGroup.setText(header);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String child = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_child, null);
    }

    TextView childText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_text);
    childText.setText(child);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the relevant code in your question is:

```
firebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = firebasedatabase.getReference("Tasks");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(tasks.size() > 0) tasks.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
          String taskName = (String) ds.child("Tasks").getValue();
          tasks.add(taskName);
        }

        expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Your code is attaching a listener to `/Tasks`, then looping over its child nodes, and getting the `Tasks` child of each of those child nodes. Yet if we look at your database structure, there is no `Tasks` subnode under each task. So that probably results in a lists of empty items, once for each child node of `/Tasks`

---

If you want to show the key of each child node of `/Tasks` (so `make a aolication` and `Shoping` in your screenshot), you'll want to use the `getKey()` of each child node:

```
firebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = firebasedatabase.getReference("Tasks");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(tasks.size() > 0) tasks.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String taskName = ds.getKey();
            tasks.add(taskName);
        }

        expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException()
    }
});
```

---

If you want to show all the values under the `Subtasks` of each child node, you'll need to add another nested loop for this:

```
firebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = firebasedatabase.getReference("Tasks");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(tasks.size() > 0) tasks.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot taskSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot subtasksSnapshot = taskSnapshot.child("Subtasks");
            for(DataSnapshot subtaskSnapshot: subtasksSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String taskName = subtaskSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tasks.add(taskName);
            }
        }

        expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException()
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably you solved my problem, but I have an error with  
`DataSnapshot subtasksSnapshot: taskSnapshot.child("Subtasks");`